# Don't pass value to component if string equals "" empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, lodash

I'm passing values to my component but some have a value of "". This creates a visual container which is empty on my view. I need the value not to pass at all if it equals "".

```
<AddIntel initialValues={{
    pastIntelNotes: [
    profile.intelNotes,
    profile.intelNotes2,
    profile.intelNotes3,
    profile.intelNotes4
]
}} />
```

I've tried a conditional

```
<AddIntel initialValues={{
    pastIntelNotes: [
    profile.intelNotes,
    profile.intelNotes2 != "" ? profile.intelNotes2 : null,
    profile.intelNotes3,
    profile.intelNotes4
]
}} />
```

`null` is being past to the component which still maps it as a length

```
initialValues:
   pastIntelNotes: Array(4)
     0: "Notes"
     1: null
     2: "Notes2"
     3: "Notes3"
length: 4
```

I am looking for this:

```
initialValues:
  pastIntelNotes: Array(3)
     0: "Notes"
     1: "Notes2"
     2: "Notes3"
length: 3
```

Comment: It seems that you looking for [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const pastIntelNotes = [profile.intelNotes, profile.intelNotes2, profile.intelNotes3, profile.intelNotes4];

<AddIntel initialValues={{
   pastIntelNotes: pastIntelNotes.filter(note => note !== ""),
}} />
```

Comment: Great, simple. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use Array's [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove unwanted values from array:

```
initialValues.filter((v) => v !== '').map(..)
```